Science fiction head implant (chip)
I am looking for the name of a movie, I watched +/- 10 years ago and really need to know its name!
Unfortunatley there are only 2 things I remember, since I watched it when I was 10 years old:

People have chips implanted in their head that record every single moment they experience.
The main character's job is to take the recordings of dead people and cut them into a short movie to show at some sort of funeral.

P.S. I already asked this question on another website, where someone thought that I've been talking about Strange Days.
I watched it but it wasn't the movie I was looking for, altought the idea was similar.

The Final Cut, starring the late Robin Williams.

Set in a world with memory recording implants, Robin Williams plays a cutter, someone with the power of final edit over people's recorded histories. His latest assignment is one that puts him in danger. 





You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details form the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

And you might want to check your spelling...j/k.  It's a definitive answer, and the blurb from the link seems to match the original question, imo.
